# How to create multiple cursors in VS code (by using keyboard shortcuts )?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I know we can create multiple cursors by **ALT + mouse click**
but I trying to figure it out how can we achieve it by Keyboard shortcuts only ?

Comment: search the keybindings for `Add cursor Down`

Comment: with [SelectBy](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by#select-by-line-number) you can add cursors by calculation, and you can remove a cursor

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version added this but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>arrow up</kbd> or down now works.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way to create additional cursors, wherever you want in the document, only by keyboard.

But I developed an extension which lets you do exactly that, create cursors and also selections, anywhere in the document, with the keyboard. It's called Keyboard Cursors and Selections (KCS): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=srares13.kcs

Comment: Previously in my answer, I merely posted a link to my extension. I was thinking that the extension's page is self explanatory in providing both the answer and how it works, but I should have also described my answer, appropriately, in words.
 
In addition, I didn’t post my extension, as an answer, anywhere else where it wouldn’t constitute a viable answer or solve the problem the OP has. With these being said, my answer may have been considered a spam, hence the downvote. Sorry for any inconvenience.
 
I edited the answer, and I hope I remediated the issue.

Comment: That is a great extension. Thanks! The only thing is that I would prefer different keyboard shortcuts. Anyway, I changed them.